# Get first and last record of a selection without using min() max()

Tags: mysql, query-performance

My energy-meter is writing the (accumulated) consumtion every minute to a db. In order to get my todays consumption I use:

```
SELECT
  (MAX(energy_kwh) - MIN(energy_kwh)) AS kwh_today
FROM logging.main_meter
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(strtime, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE();
```

Problem is: max() and min() appear to slow the query down a lot. I added a key to column `energy_kwh` but it didn't help. I bet there is a better way to get the first and last record for the calculation.

The table (its actually much bigger, ~130 columns, so I reduced it to the relevant part):

```
CREATE TABLE 'main_meter` 
( 
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  timestamp int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  strtime datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
  energy_kwh double unsigned DEFAULT '0', 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1717655 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to  the forum! Could you please tell us what server (and version) you are running?

Comment: Hello, mysql -v outputs "Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution". Its part of a XAMPP package running on my MS Server 2019 Essentials

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE logging.main_meter\G`! `DATE`s should be stored as `DATE`s and not as strings - this could be contributing to any slowdown - it's poor practice anyway!

Comment: the table is rather big. I used a simplified version to showcase the query, but here we go: `CREATE TABLE `main_meter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `strtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `energy_kwh` double unsigned DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1717655 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Comment: you are right, its actually the date that slows it down, not the min()/max() ... hmm ok then I need to find a selection based on the timestamp value I gess

Comment: And your `CREATE TABLE` statement? Use the edit link to put it into the question!

Answer (score 9):

as it turned out, it wasn't the `MIN()/MAX()` functions that slowed the query down, but the

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(strtime, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

statement. Since the table has a column with the unix-timestap, using this instead accelerates it a lot:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())
```

Query-time from ~3.6s down to ~0.02s. I call that a good improvement.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as correct (when you can... 24hrs?) so that others with the same problem can find a solution - +1 for thinking outside the box!

Comment: You've correctly identified `strtime` as the problem, it should be indexed. However, `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(strtime, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()` and `WHERE TIMESTAMP > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` are not the same. The first checks if `strtime` is at the current date. The second checks if `tiimestamp` is *after* the current date. The real problem is using `date_format` means it can't use the index.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here.

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(strtime, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

`strtime` needs to be indexed, and the query needs to be written such that MySQL can use the index. Making a function call like `date_format` on it means MySQL may not be able to use the index.

Instead, try `date`. Because `date` does a known conversion, MySQL may be able to use an index.

```
where date(strtime) = curdate()
```

Otherwise, eliminate non-deterministic function calls entirely.

```
where curdate() <= strtime and strtime < curdate() + interval 1 day;
```

We can't use `where strtime between curdate() and curdate() + interval 1 day` because that is inclusive an would include midnight on the next day.

---

Note that the `timestamp` column is redundant with `strtime` if they are meant to contain the same time. Instead, replace `timestamp` with `unix_timstamp(strtime)`.

Comment: Slighlty odd way of saying it. I would have flipped the first half of the interval check: `where strtime >= curdate() and strtime < curdate() + interval 1 day` still half-open interval, just easier to comprehend.

Comment: @Charlieface It's deliberate to emulate the syntactically invalid but clear `lower-bound <= value < upper-bound` showing the value is between the bounds.

Comment: @Charlieface doing comparisons in number line order is [a stylistic choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188857/71059) which many find easier to read

Answer (score 1):

1. switch the datetime comparision so u dont apply funciton on column but on curdate. Ie. Strtime between A and B.
2. primary key on energy_kwh  is not very usefull here i think. And risky. What if there is a timespan with 0 energy consumption. No change in value, PK violation.
3. add index on strtime,, move dattime calculation to other side and it should be ok.

Comment: I think I found a good solution now: `SELECT
  (MAX(energy_kwh) - MIN(energy_kwh)) AS kwh_today
FROM logging.main_meter
WHERE TIMESTAMP > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` Selection based on timestamp column is much faster

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the correct time format, instead of scooping up a whole day and finding the first and last records, why don't you search for (only) the record in the first minute of the day and (only) the record in the last minute of the day?